# CentOS Superblock corruption?

Tags: filesystems, storage-area-network, corruption

I'm on CentOS 5.2 and I'm having a problem booting my two database servers.  Our IT department performed a SAN upgrade over the weekend and now I can't boot - they say the upgrade went fine but obviously something has happened.  The error I get a boot time is this;

```
fsck.ext3: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/VolGroup01/db
```

I have an external consultant who is looking at it and saying its a Superblock problem which can't be fixed, but thought these were recoverable (according to this at least; http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/recover-bad-superblock-from-corrupted-partition/)

Anyone have any suggestions or pointers?  Also, for future reference, what should I keep backups of beyond my data?

---

Utterly desperate and willing to pay for recovery at this point.

Comment: Are you sure your SAN-targets are still the same (i.e. yours)? What does "your" IT-department say about this (your are not in that department?)? I think they lost your SAN-targets or did mix them up.

Comment: Thanks Nils, I'll ask that question.  When we looked at 11pm last night they appeared to be correct.  The SAN specialist we had on site suggested removing and remapping them, which we did, and which made no difference.

Comment: I'm not a part of IT no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And its all back and fixed.  Turns out someone had mounted the LUNs to a Windows machine in error, then removed and put them onto the CentOS VMs without thinking it would cause a problem.  Each partition was labelled as a "MICROSOFT RESERVED PARTITION" - used the cached LVM setting to bring it back.

Comment: Can't take credit for it I'm afraid, it was one of our consultants.  I'll mark this as accepted as soon serverfault will let me.

Answer (score 3):

I am willing to bet you know that the SAN has shifted the beginning of the physical disk off by a few bytes. I've seen this before. Its a bitch to get your files off of a disk that has done this but it is possible.

If you run 'fdisk -l' do you get messages about the starting cylinders on the device not marrying up? Its usually in brackets around each partition declaration.

Do you manage to find the LVM groups but not the disk itself? Is the LVM device made up of multiple SAN disks and just one is affected?

The following script is going to *try* to search for the correct offset on /dev/sdb where your lvm partition starts. No guarantees it will find anything. If it does, you might be in a good position to recover your data.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
def BoyerMooreHorspool(pattern, text):
    m = len(pattern)
    n = len(text)
    if m > n: return -1
    skip = []
    for k in range(256): skip.append(m)
    for k in range(m - 1): skip[ord(pattern[k])] = m - k - 1
    skip = tuple(skip)
    k = m - 1
    while k < n:
        j = m - 1; i = k
        while j >= 0 and text[i] == pattern[j]:
            j -= 1; i -= 1
        if j == -1: return i + 1
        k += skip[ord(text[k])]
    return -1

if __name__ == '__main__':
   giveup = 1024*1024*1024*2
   lba_offset = 0
   text = ""
   disk = open('/dev/sdb', 'r')
   while disk.tell() < giveup:
      #print "Checking: %f" % (lba_offset/(1024*1024))
      text = disk.read(1048576)
      s = BoyerMooreHorspool("\x00\x00\x00LVM2", text)
      if s > -1:
         print "Try offset: %d" % ((lba_offset+int(s))-533)
         sys.exit(0)
      else:
         lba_offset += 1048576
   print "Unable to find LVM position!"
```

Can you return what output you get?

Comment: Happened during a SAN upgrade yep, here's the output of your command - http://www.screenshots.cc/photos/thumb/54582-ff8z6.jpg  - Any help greatly appreciated as just been informed by IT that we only have partial backups

Comment: do you have the non-thumbnail image?

Comment: Sorry, try http://www.screenshots.cc/photos/original/54582-ff8z6.jpg

Comment: or http://www.screenshots.cc/photos/original/54582-ff8z6.jpg - i seemed to have picked the worst image host for this, sorry.

Comment: What physical disks make up /dev/VolGroup00/db?

Comment: Not sure how to find out to be honest, its on a single raw mapped lun if that's what you mean?

Comment: /dev/sdb I believe

Comment: I've added a script that may find where your LVM2 disk is positionally on your SAN disk. If it finds it you might be in a position to recover your data.

Comment: Why won't grep do the same thing?

Comment: I wasnt able to grep for null characters :(.

Comment: How would GREP do the same thing?

Comment: Thanks for the script, it returned that it was unable to find the LVM position.

Comment: This should probably be converted into a chat at this stage, not sure how I can make that happen though. Either the LVM exists 'behind' the disk (as the disk moved out a few bytes), or the LVM partition is a large number of bytes beyond the start >2G anyway), or the problem is not to do with the SAN shifting the offset of the drive around.

Comment: That would be great, I've got a meeting with both our internal IT team and my department's external Linux consultants this morning to go through our options - any help from you would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into single-user mode and comment out the line mounting that filesystem in /etc/fstab.  That should let you boot and take a look at why that filesystem won't mount.

Comment: I get a prompt, could I just use umount?

Comment: If you get prompt you probably already are in single user mode.

Comment: So I've moved on a few steps, I'm certain its a superblock issues, getting this;  dumpe2fs couldn't find a valid filesystem superblock